# How is payload data represented by Session Initiation Protocol?

Tags: protocols, sip, payload, data-communication

I am wondering what is payload data and how is payload data represented by Session Initiation Protocol?

Answer (score 1):

`Payload data` is referring to the body of the SIP request or response. It is completely arbitrary and can consist of anything. It's similar to the body of an `HTTP` request.

The most common payload you will see on SIP messages are Session Description Protocol (SDP) offers and answers. They use a `Content-Type` of `application/sdp` are are text based payloads.